# How to enable device frame in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am using Android Studio version 2.2.3 and since I have installed it There is no device frame included when we have a preview(as shown in the image). I have tried a lot but there seems to be no option to include a device frame.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Just lost the device skin after updating Android Emulator.

I fixed it by manually editing the AVD `config.ini` and adding:

```
skin.name=pixel_4
skin.path=D:\sdk\skins\pixel_4
```

Posting this so I can find the answer faster next time it happens and maybe help others, it seems it is still a valid bug even with Android Studio Chipmunk

Comment: And where can I find this `config.ini` file?

Comment: it's where the avd is installed. the easiest way to get to it is from android studio, in Device Manager, press the arrow down ( where you also have the start avd button ) and select "Show on Disk"

Answer (score 1):

There is no device frame included from the newer version by the Android Studio itself. But, you can still use a skin while using AVD.

Comment: What do you mean by "skin"? The frame? How?

Comment: As written I am not sure this is true.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a frame in Android studio. In the device manager, to open the **Virtual Device Configuration**, click on the pencil icon beside the device you would like to add a frame to.  When the dialog window opens, click on the button **Show Advanced Settings**. Scroll down and find the section **Device Frame** near the bottom (Tested on Android Giraffe in August 2023). There you can select the check box for **Enable Device Frame**. From the list you can then choose a suitable frame. This is how I was able to choose the correct frame for my Pixel4a emulator.

Answer (score -2):

DEVICE FRAME CAN BE VIEW BY

1- Click on designer preview window

2 - press F button from your keyboard

this will enable and disable the designer preview device frame every time you press F button from your keyboard.